# Limiting distribution of scaled sum of squared Poisson RVs

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Let $Y_1,Y_2,...$ be $\text{iid}$ Poisson random variables having mean $1$. Define

$$U_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i^2}.$$

How to determine the limiting distribution of the sequence $U_1,U_2, ...$?

I know that the weak law of large numbers can be used to deal with the  $n^{-1}\sqrt{\sum Y_i^2}$, but not how to deal with the $n^{-1/2}$ case.

Comment: I am asking how to determine the limiting distribution of the sequence of U's

Comment: Which exercise from which book is this? If it is.

Answer (score 1):

The central limit theorem (at least some version of it) tells us that with 
$$
  U_n^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2
$$
the following converges in distribution to a standard normal $Z$ for large $n$,
$$
  \sqrt{n} \frac{U_n^2-\mu}{\sigma^2} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} Z
$$
with $\mu=\text{E}[Y^2]$ and $\sigma^2=\text{Var}[Y^2]=\text{E}[Y^4]-\text{E}[Y^2]^2$. Therefore, the limiting distribution of $U_n$ is going to be 
$$
  U_n\ \overset{d}{=}\ \sqrt{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}} Z}
$$
The only real difficulty here is to determine the 2nd and 4th moment of $Y$. Luckily, because $Y$ is Poisson with mean 1 we can use [Dobinsky's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula):
$$
  \text{E}[Y^i] = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{k^i}{k!}
$$
which for $i=1,2,3,4$ gives 1, 2, 5, 15 respectively. Therefore $\mu=2$ and $\sigma^2=15-2^2=11$.

Comment: I do not quite follow... Don't you mean $U_{n}^2 = n^{-1} \sum Y_{i}^2$?

Comment: Didn't you mean "$\sigma$" instead of "$\sigma^2$" in the denominator of the second formula?  That would change the third formula, too.  It's hard to see how Dobinsky's Formula is any help, unless you can point to an alternative way of computing the Bell numbers.